# Go to a route if at least one guard is active

Tags: angular, angular2-guards

The guards in Angular2 routing run in the order they are provided.
But in the case of guards with observables, even if the first guard is true, angular ignores it, and only apply the result from the second guard's observable.

How can I solve this?

```
const mainRoutes: Routes = [
  {
  path: 'app',
  component:MainComponent,
  canActivate:[AuthGuard],
  children:[
     { path: 'dashboard',  component: DashboardComponent },
     { path: 'protectedRoute',  component: ProtectedRouteComponent, canActivate:[Admin1Guard,Admin2Guard] }
  ]}
];
```

The first guard:

```
canActivate() :Observable<boolean>{
    return this.authService.getUser().map(res=>{
        if(res.user.role=="admin1")
          return true;
      }).take(1);
   }
 }
```

The second guard:

```
canActivate() :Observable<boolean>{
    return this.authService.getUser().map(res=>{
        if(res.user.role=="admin2")
          return true;
      }).take(1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sounds like normal behavior. If **at least** one of the guards returns false, then the `canActivate` property will prevent the user from accessing the route. So in your case if `Admin1Guard` returns true and `Admin2Guard` returns false, access should NOT be granted. Is the code you showed the real code? Why do you need two observables to test the same property?

Comment: Well I would like to route if at least one of them is true (an OR relation between the guards).
I have many roles in the app, and each role has access to some parts (and of course there are parts accessible by many roles), that's why I created a guard for each role.
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would refactor the role-checking logic into a **single, generic** `CheckRoleGuard` service and attach the name of the role to check to the route via the `data` property:

```ts
{
  path: 'protectedRoute1',
  component: SomeComponent,
  canActivate: [CheckRoleGuard],
  data: { allowedRoles: ['admin','editor'] }
},
{
  path: 'protectedRoute2',
  component: SomeComponent,
  canActivate: [CheckRoleGuard],
  data: { allowedRoles: ['admin'] }
}
```

And now for the the `RoleGuard` service:

```ts
@Injectable()
class CheckRoleGuard {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    // Retrieve the allowed roles from `route.data`.
    const allowedRoles = route.data['allowedRoles'];

    return this.authService.getUser()
      .map(data => {
        return allowedRoles.indexOf(data.user.role) !== -1;
      });
  }

}
```

Comment: You are right, it is better to do it this way, but your answer needs a few small fixes (which I made in a edit, awaiting it's approval)

Comment: I've added other minor improvements in line with your edit (e.g. injecting `AuthService`). What's the use of the `.take(1)` in this code?

Comment: I've injected the service in my original code,  ActivatedRouteSnapshot, however didn't work when I try to inject it, do you have any idea why?
(take(1) takes the first event emitted by the observable)
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/take.html

Comment: Try injecting `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` in the `canActivate()` method vs the constructor. `take(1)` isn't required for HTTP requests (they either return only ONE value or they fail). See updated answer.

Comment: That's what I did, but the first answer, you injected it in the constructor, that's why I said it didn't work.
And you are right, take in this case does nothing, it can only be useful in case of a stream of events